# Generating separate .o's for dependent files

Tags: c

### e1.c

```
#include<stdio.h>
extern struct members;
int main(){
        printf("\n %d \n",members.a1);
        printf("%d",add(2,2));
        printf("%d",sub(2,2));

}
```

### e2.c

```
typedef struct members_t{
        int a1;
        int b1;
}members;
int add(int a,int b){
        return (a+b);
}
int sub(int a,int b){
        return (a-b);
}
```

I need to generate the .o's separately and need to combine both the .o's while creating an exectable to resolve the dependencies.

I compiled the e1.c separately and got the below error,

```
[root@angus]# gcc -c e1.c -o e1.o
e1.c:2: warning: useless storage class specifier in empty declaration
e1.c: In function ‘main’:
e1.c:4: error: ‘members’ undeclared (first use in this function)
e1.c:4: error: (Each undeclared identifier is reported only once
e1.c:4: error: for each function it appears in.)
```

How to generate both the .o's separately without errors.

I used extern to notify the compiler that this is defined somewhere, but still get the above error.

Comment: Put the `struct`-declaration in a header that both files include.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The compiler must have the full declaration of your `struct members_t` as well as the declaration(prototype) for your add() and sub() functions when you're compiling e1.c, so you should place that in a header file.

**Step 1.**
Move declarations to a header file.

Create your new header file that looks like:

```
#ifndef E_HEADER_H
#define E_HEADER_H

 typedef struct members_t{
        int a1;
        int b1;
}members;
int add(int a,int b);
int sub(int a,int b);
#endif
```

And name this `e.h`

**Step 2.**

Add

```
#include "e.h"
```

to both e1.c and e2.c.

**Step 3.**

Remove the declaration for struct members_t from e2.c

**Step 4.**

Remove the forward declaration of `extern struct members;` from e1.c

**Step 5.**

Fix the code. You need to actually create an instance of your members struct, and initialize its
members

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "e.h"
int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
        members m;
        m.a1 = 1;
        m.a2 = 2;
        printf("\n %d \n",m.a1);
        printf("%d",add(2,2));
        printf("%d",sub(2,2));

}
```

Then you can compile the files as you're trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

`struct members` is a type. `members` is not an object, and `members.a1` is a syntax error. What the others say about putting the type definition in a header file is correct, but in addition you need to define an object of that type.